# How to send multiple items of recyclerview from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have an `ArrayList` of type Course. Course has id ( string ), name ( string ).
I want to display a list of courses on one screen. Give the user option to select multiple courses which they have completed and send these courses to next activity.
I am able to `MultiSelect` courses in a `RecyclerView`. But unable to send the data to another activity.

Comment: Create a new array list of selected courses and then google `Serializable` and `Parcelable`

Comment: @JunaidKhalid: That approach is not advisable. Now you have multiple copies of your data, and you no longer have a single source of truth. Plus, there are caps as to how big your list can be, before you start running into `TransactionTooLargeException` crashes.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK please enlighten us with optimized approach

Comment: One approach is to have one activity instead of two, using fragments or composables for the screens. Another approach is to pass the list of IDs of the selected courses in an `Intent` extra. Have the courses themselves be available from some central repository, so the second activity can retrieve the data for those courses based on those IDs. See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide for more.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the data to JSON string & pass easily between activities using intent bundles...

create extension functions like these

```
// convert safely from json to class
fun <T> String.fromSafeJson(classOfT: Class<T>): T? {
    return try {
        Gson().fromJson(this, classOfT)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}

// convert any object to json
fun Any.toJson(): String {
    return Gson().toJson(this)
}
```

after that you can convert any list of any type using `yourList.toJson()`, send it via bundle and in next activity get it from bundle and parse using `stringName.fromSafeJson(YourListType)`

remember to add Gson library... use can use the following

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
```